# Need help vertically aligning text in HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css

```css
.Cube {
  float: left;
  height: 16vw;
  width: 16vw;
  background-color: #545454;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Cube">
  <a href="#">Random Stuff</a>
</div>
```

So I've been practicing website making with html5 and CSS and I want to make a square with text in the middle. I get the horizontal alignment but the vertical alignment just doesn't want to work.

Comment: use flex for it

Answer (score 1):

In this case / if it's a single line, I think the simplest solution is adding the same line-height as the height of the element.

```
line-height: 16vw;
```

```css
.Cube {
  float: left;
  height: 16vw;
  width: 16vw;
  line-height: 16vw;
  background-color: #545454;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Cube">
  <a href="#">Random Stuff</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your CSS

```
line-height : 16vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css will work as well:

```
align-items: center; 
display: flex;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try  `display:inline;` with your CSS Code

```
.Cube {
  float: left;
  height: 16vw;
  width: 16vw;
  background-color: #545454;
  display:inline;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use padding to align your division from the top,

```
padding-top: 50px;
```